# Bash loop - tokenize on lines rather than words

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, token

I'm writing a script to do variable substitution into a Java properties file, of the format name=value. I have a source file, source.env like this:

```
TEST_ENV_1=test environment variable one
TEST_ENV_2=http://test.environment.com/one
#this is a comment with an equal sign=blah
TEST_ENV_3=/var/log/test/env/2.log
```

My script will replace every occurence of TEST_ENV_1 in the file dest.env with "test environment variable one", and so on.

I'm trying to process a line at a time, and having problems because looping on output from a command like sed or grep tokenizes on white space rather than the entire line:

```
$ for i in `sed '/^ *#/d;s/#.*//' source.env`; do
  echo $i
  done
TEST_ENV_1=test
environment
variable
one
TEST_ENV_2=http://test.environment.com/one
TEST_ENV_3=/var/log/test/env/2.log
```

How do I treat them as lines? What I want to be able to do is split each line apart on the "=" sign and make a sed script with a bunch of substitution regex's based on the source.env file.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed '/^ *#/d;s/#.*//' source.env | while read LINE; do
  echo "$LINE"
done
```

An alternative is to change `$IFS` as per @Jim's answer. It's better to avoid backticks in this case as they'll cause the entire file to be read in at once, whereas piping the output of sed to `while` above will allow the file to be processed line by line without reading the whole thing in to memory.

Comment: Indeed, this concisely answers the question.